# How to get file type from encrypted file?

Tags: c#, encryption, caesar-cipher

How do I get the **file type** using `C#` from an encrypted file (i.e. `file.enc`)?

**Encryption Method:** Shift Cipher Z<sub>256</sub>

**Shift Cipher Encryption:**

Y<sub>i</sub> = (X<sub>i</sub> + k) % 256

X<sub>i</sub> = (Y<sub>i</sub> - k) % 256

**Where:**

X<sub>i</sub>, i = 1 : n, is the input in plain bytes.

Y<sub>i</sub>, i = 1 : n, is the output cipher bytes.

k is the shift key which is a secret byte between 1 and 255.

If I have to decrypt the file first, how could I decrypt it without using exhaustive search to find the **shift key**?

I'm not talking about getting `.enc` as I can already easily do that. I'm not able to determine how the file was before encryption such as `.doc`, `.xls`, `.pdf`, `.jpg`, or `.wav` file types.

What I have tried:

```
byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(openFileDialog1.FileName);

// Mean
double mean = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
{
    mean += byteArray[i];
}

mean = mean / byteArray.Length;
txtMean.Text = mean.ToString("#.000");

// Median
byteArray.ToList().Sort();
int median = byteArray[(int)Math.Floor((decimal)(byteArray.Length / 2))];
txtMedian.Text = median.ToString();

// Mode
var groups = byteArray.GroupBy(g => g);
int maxCount = groups.Max(g => g.Count());
int mode = groups.First(g => g.Count() == maxCount).Key;
txtMode.Text = mode.ToString();

// Standard Deviation
double standardDeviation = byteArray.Select(value => (value - mean) * (value - mean)).Sum();
standardDeviation = Math.Sqrt(standardDeviation / byteArray.Length);
txtStandardDeviation.Text = standardDeviation.ToString("#.000");

// Entropy (I don't know how to get this part.)
int entropy = 0;
txtEntropy.Text = entropy.ToString();
```

So, from this you can see I take the file, read all bytes of the file and find the `mean`, `median`, `mode`, `standard deviation`, and `entropy` values.

By the way, I don't know how to find the entropy value for the file, is there some formula for this or maybe a C# built-in method? I have searched, but found nothing.

I thought using the `mode` value would be able to determine the file type, but rather it only determines `.pdf` files as `.pdf` files have a mode of 48.

`.doc`, `.xls`, `.docx`, `.xlsx`, `.jpg`, and `.wav` files all give me a mode of 0.

I have also tried reading the bytes using the following page(s):

ASCII Character Codes Chart 1 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60ecse8t(v=vs.80).aspx
ASCII Character Codes Chart 2 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hxt0028(v=vs.80).aspx

using this code:

```
string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteArray).Substring(0, 256);
```

but it just returns gibberish in which I am unable to determine the difference in file types.

Comment: The _whole point_ of encryption is to make it impossible to read anything about the plaintext.

Comment: @SLaks - True, but in this case it is a simple encryption using Shift Cipher. I can decrypt the file first using exhaustive search to find the shift key, but there is a better way to go about doing that and that is where I am having this issue.

Comment: @ArtjomB. - Okay, I edited the question to include the encryption method and the part about the shift key without using exhaustive search.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I added more information about the Shift Cipher.

Comment: @ArtjomB. - It technically is Caesar Cipher, but it uses 256 ASCII Character Codes (rather than the normal 26 Alphabetic Characters) from the links that are available in the question body.

Comment: I would still think it is easier to decrypt/brute force the file before trying to determine the file type. Files such as pdf have vastly different footprints. There are pdfs that are plain text, others are nearly pure noise. xlsx and docx are simple zip files, so if you do a frequency analysis, you won't get far. I can't say anything about doc and xls. jpg and wav are very noisy, but wav may contain more patterns than jpg.

Comment: @ArtjomB. - How would I be able to tell when the brute force method succeeds? The encrypted file is 60,000 characters in length. I would have to make 256 output files and read each to find one that isn't gibberish. There has to be a better way. Is there some other way to determine the file type after decryption?

Comment: My guess is that every file format has some magic marker/prefix that you can test for. For example the leading "PK" for zip files. You don't need to encrypt the whole thing just to look inside the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a '**Caesar Shift**', then you just run down the alphabet, trying each possible shift, there are only 25 of them.

```
NBCM CM UH YRUGJFY
nbcm cm uh yrugjfy
ocdn dn vi zsvhkgz
pdeo eo wj atwilha
qefp fp xk buxjmib
rfgq gq yl cvyknjc
sghr hr zm dwzlokd
this is an example
uijt jt bo fybnqmf
vjku ku cp gzcorng
wklv lv dq hadpsoh
xlmw mw er ibeqtpi
ymnx nx fs jcfruqj
znoy oy gt kdgsvrk
aopz pz hu lehtwsl
bpqa qa iv mfiuxtm
cqrb rb jw ngjvyun
drsc sc kx ohkwzvo
estd td ly pilxawp
ftue ue mz qjmybxq
guvf vf na rknzcyr
hvwg wg ob sloadzs
iwxh xh pc tmpbeat
jxyi yi qd unqcfbu
kyzj zj re vordgcv
lzak ak sf wpsehdw
mabl bl tg xqtfiex
nbcm cm uh yrugjfy
```

Comment: No, it's a Shift Cipher with Z<sub>256</sub> which is why I linked the ASCII Character Code tables.

Comment: Then you only have 256 possibilities to try.  That is 2^8, which provides no security at all from a brute force attack.  Just try every possibility.

Comment: Can you edit your answer so I can rate your answer up? Your answer ended up being correct. I ended up finding the shift key from trial and error. I had to decrypt the bytes first to find the file type so you were right. I marked your answer as correct, but I'd like to change my rating to +1 so if you edit your answer and save edit I'll be able to change your rating for you.